# Incorrect GCD algorithm

Tags: c++

I have everything else right in my code except the calculation from my do-while loop is coming out to zero every time. I do not know why this is happening. Here is the function in which the code is:    (i have to use a do while loop)

edit: even after adding the brackets, it still goes to 0. the example inputs i am using are 200 and 45. the answer should come out to 5 correct?

```
    int calculate_GCD(int value1, int value2){
      int big;          
      int small;
      int r;    //remainder
      int GCD;

       if(value1>value2){
         big = value1;
         small = value2;
         }
       else{
         big = value2;
         small = value1;
         }
       do{
         r = big % small;

         if(r == 0)
           GCD = small;
         else{
             big = small;
             small = r;
             } 
         } 
       while(r != 0);

       return(GCD);
       }
```

any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You wrote the code, so you do know what is going on. Just trace it using the debugger or even by hand to see where it goes wrong.  Take a sample input, and go through the code to see where it deviates from what you expected it to do...

Comment: if r is the remainder of the integer division between two ints, it surely can go to 0!

Comment: Regarding your edit: The corrected code works fine, did you remember to recompile?

Comment: i ran the code section by itself and it works, the values i am passing in are what is the issue so I am working that out now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to have brackets after the else.

```
else
{
    big = value2;
    small = value1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to enclose in braces two statements after the else

```
   else
     big = value2;
     small = value1;
```

There shall be

```
   else
   {
     big = value2;
     small = value1;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

This code does not do what you think it does:

```
else
     big = value2;
     small = value1;
```

Here's what it actually does:

```
else
     big = value2; // Sometimes do this

small = value1;  // ALWAYS do this
```

Here's what you want:

```
else
{
     big = value2;
     small = value1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are never changing the values of big and small - and they control the value of r by their computed mod value.

Hence your loop will go on forever, if "r" is not zero the first time around - i.e. when the do - while is first executed.